# How to use helper functions with Apollo GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, redux, apollo, react-apollo

I find myself in situations with React/Redux apps where I require a lot of functions to transform data when it comes back from the server by using libaries like moment or jwtDecode. For example:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getAllTokens: () => {
            dispatch(getAllTokens());
        }
    };
}
```

On page load, I run `this.props.getAllTokens()` to bring back all tokens from the server stored in the database which I'd like to show on the page (for example).

The dispatch uses Redux Thunk to perform some operations on the data and send to the store:

```
export const getAllTokens = () => dispatch => {
    apiGetAllUsers()
        .then(tokens => {
            let newFormat = tokens.message.map(token => {
                if (token.refreshToken) {
                    let decoded = jwtDecode(token.refreshToken);
                    let expiresIn = moment.unix(decoded.exp).fromNow();

                    return {
                        refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
                        email: token.email,
                        expiresIn
                    };
                }
            });
            dispatch(adminTokensReceived(newFormat));
        })
};
```

This function `getAllTokens` is in another file to help the component keep lean. This approach works fine for Redux, but when it comes to using Apollo instead, how would I update the data before adding it back to the component props?

I have came across [this link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-props-option) which shows how to update data from a query, but I don't see many examples using it, so I wondered if I'm missing something fundamental?

So my questions is, what is the best way to use helper functions as I've described above?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The docs show to transform the incoming GraphQL response into whatever shape you need using `props`. So if the response is basically in the same shape as it was when you were using REST, you would utilize the same logic inside `props`?

Comment: Yeah that's one way, but I was wondering if there's a more common practice for dealing with such situations as I hadn't seen the `props` example used anywhere.

Comment: `props` is what you would use. You could simply keep the parser function in a separate file, and whatever component uses a query that needs that parser function, just use `props` with that so the component gets its props in the shape you want them.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for responding both of you